# Using grep, sed, etc. to get at specific data, but it's not working

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I'm using this command:

```
pdftotext statement.pdf - | grep -m 1 "Provider" | sed -n "/Provider/,/Amount/p"
```

The file has the line:

```
Patient Jane Person Date 01/01/13 Provider John Q Doctor Amount $100
```

What I want is for the command to return "John Q Doctor" -- basically anything that's between the word Provider and the word Amount.

But, when I run that command, all I get is the entire line again -- not just the string "John Q Doctor". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use sed:

```
sed 's/.*Provider\(.*\)Amount.*/\1/'
```

With Grep(GNU):

```
grep -oP '(?<=Provider).*(?=Amount.*)'
```

Comment: +1. Minor nitpick, both examples would include extraneous whitespace in the output.

Comment: Doesn't work. :(  It just gives me the entire file back, not just the words, "John Q Doctor"...

Answer (score 1):

sed range commands work on the entire matching lines, try this if they are on the same line:

```
pdftotext statement.pdf - | grep -m 1 "Provider" | 
     sed -n "s/Provider\(.*\)Amount/\1/p"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed -n '/Provider/{s/.*Provider\(.*\)Amount.*/\1/p;q}'
```

this should work +